# MySql Prevent/track duplicate field across multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

I'm looking for an easy way to check across multiple part tables to determine if a given part number is already present before adding it to a given table.

The current best idea I have come up with is a secondary table that simply lists every PN from all tables in a single column with a unique key; however I was wondering if there is a way to do it without creating a new table and index?

For the visual learner types, I have forty-some tables that more or less follow this pattern:

Table 1

```
    |    id    |    PN     |    Other Columns    |  
    ----------------------------------------------  
    |    1     |  SomePn   |   ... ... ... ...   |
        ...
```

Table 2

```
    |    id    |    PN     |    Still Other Columns  |
    --------------------------------------------------
    |    1     |  OtherPn  |  ... ... ... ... ...    |
        ...
```

and about forty more as above, with up to 50 columns and up to 8 million records per table.

The goal is, whether through software (Java) or MySql rejecting the records, to prevent duplicate part numbers from creeping in across multiple tables.  Is a master PN table the only possible or reasonable solution?

I know that the data structure is not the best design, and a rework is in progress, but I would like to know some suggested best practices as well as suggested solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a table is your best option.

Table 1:

```
|  t1_id   |    PN     |    Other Columns    |  
----------------------------------------------  
|    1     |  pn_id    |   ... ... ... ...   |
    ...
```

Table 2:

```
|  t2_id   |    PN     |    Other Columns    |  
----------------------------------------------  
|    1     |  pn_id    |   ... ... ... ...   |
    ...
```

Table 3:

```
|  pn_id   |  PN  |
------------------
|    1     |  ##  |
    ...
```

Although this may not be the easiest to implement solution in your case, it is the best overall solution, as you will have no scaling problems now or in the future. If you instead opted for a solution which checked all the tables for duplicate part numbers on update/creation, this would take longer and longer as your tables got bigger.

If you could guarantee that they would never get bigger or you would never add part numbers, you could probably get away with just writing a script to check for duplicates once and not worry about another table at all. But, in the long run, you'll want to add another table just to keep track of the part numbers.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured, was just wondering if there were any other ways that could work.  The data tables are always expanding so the table is definitely the best option then.  Thanks for your reply!